# How to mock the UserAgent property for an HttpRequest in a unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, httprequest, httpcontext

I am trying to create a fake `HttpContext` for my unit test and also wanted to set the `UserAgent` property.

I tried the below code, but it failed saying platform not supported.

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest(null, "http:xyz.com", null);
httpRequest.Headers["UserAgent"] = "unitTest";

var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
HttpContext context = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the reference source, the [`UserAgent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,ba97f58894912f14) is extracted form the `HttpWorkerRequest`. The only way to change it, is by calling [this constructor of `HttpRequest`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,ba97f58894912f14) using reflection in order to pass the worker request in:

```
internal HttpRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

As I am further investigating, it seems it retrieves the properties from some far away `IIS` class, or when using ISAPI using the [Server variable `ALL_RAW`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/ISAPIWorkerRequest.cs,725).

I am starting to think this might become a horrible thing to get mocked up. You might have more luck overriding the [abstract class `HttpWorkerRequest`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/WorkerRequest.cs,988a14294f0ce26d) yourself, but it might become a nightmare to implement.

Comment: yeah!! am finding it very difficult, even if I use reflection and call the internal constructor , i dont know how to provide HttpWorkerRequest object .  I found HttpWorkerRequest  is an abstract class

Comment: You should use one of the deriving classes, or create your own. Either way, this is going to be hard...